# Bootcamp and Macbook Pro and TrueCrypt

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition

I am using Bootcamp on my Macbook Pro and have Windows 7 installed.

Unfortunately, due to the changing nature of my work, I need to switch to full time Windows, and encrypt my laptop.  I'm going to delete my OSX partition, leaving only my Windows 7 partition, and install Truecrypt, but I get the message saying that the first 32 kB of my system drive needs to be free in order to use TrueCrypt.

With the Macbook Pro, it looks like there is a 200MB GPT partition at the beginning of the drive.  If I'm going to use Windows 7 exclusively on this MBP, can I delete that 200 MB partition, or will this cause me booting issues?

Comment: Any reason you need TrueCrypt (which is no longer developed and known to be insecure)? Any reason you can't use Windows' own BitLocker encryption? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

The first partition on an Apple Disk Utility drive is a 200MB EFI System Partition. OS X 10.8 and older do not need it for booting, but it is used for staging firmware updates. If it's removed, firmware updates won't be possible. Depending on exactly what TrueCrypt wants, you could resize the EFI System Partition, as 200MB isn't really required, by changing the start sector and then reformatting the EFI System partition (as FAT32).

Comment: Can you add some details about which actual steps would be required to get this done?